# Can I report about bug in system that I don't use?

Tags: bug-reporting

Let's say I remember that I found some bug in Kubuntu or Ubuntu. But now I use Xubuntu. How could I report those bug ? Or it is necessary to run those ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you report a bug on a different system no one can answer with what you can do to fix the bug because you can't implement their solutions. Neither can you answer questions about contents of specific configuration files or programs installed since you no longer have them.

You could find similar bugs and post a comment there saying "This happened to me once before but I can't reproduce it now".

You need to report the bug as it happens and will be asked to submit system information at the same time. As such you can't report a bug for an old system you were running because your current logs won't be compatible. Refer to launchpad.net for examples of bug reports.

Some bugs are automatically reported as they happen in Ubuntu when a crash happens. You don't have to do anything special but you won't know what is being done to fix it.

Some automatic bug reports will be ignored if you are running a mainline kernel such as `4.14.34` which although released by Ubuntu isn't supported by Ubuntu.

**NOTE:** This is for reporting bugs about Ubuntu in lauchpad.net. Other developers can have different rules.

Comment: But I just filled a bug on https://bugs.kde.org/ and nobody asked me what system I use and no commands were typed.

Comment: I was talking about Ubuntu and bug reports on launchpad.net. Other developers will have other rules.

Comment: Then it should be clarified in answer.

Comment: I added a note. On Ask Ubuntu most questions are about Ubuntu so we don't generally qualify answers to say it's about Ubuntu. However since Ubuntu relies on other developers such as Debian, Gnome, etc. there are other bug reporting sites.

Comment: I edited my question. Sorry.

Comment: I've edit my answer. Generally it's discouraged in **Ask Ubuntu** to change a question after it's been answered.